# Java JDBC DataSource Deployment for MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to learn how to use JDBC and in the Java Tutorial on JDBC (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html), it says the system admin needs to create a BasicDataSource Object, set its properties, and Registering the DataSource object with a naming service using the following code:

```
com.dbaccess.BasicDataSource ds = new com.dbaccess.BasicDataSource();
ds.setServerName("grinder");
ds.setDatabaseName("CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS");
ds.setDescription("Customer accounts database for billing");

Context ctx = new InitialContext();
ctx.bind("jdbc/billingDB", ds);
```

and then the developer can use the deployed DataSource Object to get a Connection.

Currently, I'm using MySQL and downloaded the Connector/J but I'm confused as to how to deploy the the DataSource. From my understanding, the BasicDataSource is deployed on the server. Since I set up my MySQL server to be on my local machine, does that mean I need to create another Java Program that creates this DataSource so my user program can connect to it or does it mean I need to configure my MySQL server?

Comment: DataSources are used when running in an application server (EJB, JBoss, Tomcat, Jetty, ...). That's the server they referred to, not the database server. For relatively simple standalone programs, you might not use DataSource at all, and simply get the connection by calling one of the [`DriverManager.getConnection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#i1) methods.

Comment: You need a servlet engine or Java EE app server (not necessary for this case) and a MySQL database.  You configure the pooled data source using JNDI  in the servlet engine.

Comment: You are the system admin for your local servlet engine.  https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Comment: @Andreas Thanks! That clarifies it up quite a bit. I think I'll look into running an application server and get DataSource to work. I saw the DriverManager could make a connection but it seems like using DataSource is the better design practice, or at least it's recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Comments above should be enough to reach your goal by yourself.
But, if you are inpatient here is a code snippet to make it easier:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //pz is the name of database, user is user name, password is password for the user
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/pz?" +
            "user=root&password=root")) {
        // Do something with connection, e.g:
        System.out.println("conn: " + connection.getCatalog());


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

MySql J connector I used is *mysql-connector-java-8.0.9-rc-bin.jar*
(And you'll get the warning about SSL like this:

*Fri Jul 20 20:16:10 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.*